# Changing a UIImageView when a certain row is selected on a UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uipickerview

Hopefully someone can help with this, I have a UIPickerView which prompts my user to select a Height and a Weight from the Picker.  When selected, it then populates a UILabel with the selected option.  Next to each label I want to put a UIImageView which initially starts out displaying a Cross to indicate the required action has not been taken.  Then when the user select their values it changes that Image to a tick.

But I cant for the life of me figure out how to go about doing it?

Any advice?  Would I place this in the didSelectRow method of the UIPickerView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView can be init'ed with two images, normal and highlighted.

```
(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image highlightedImage:(UIImage *)highlightedImage
```

Select which one you want to be displayed via the highlighted property.

The picker view's delegate function

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

can be the place where you set your label and update the highlighted property of the UIImageView.